# Move constructor of class containing only movable std::map not working

Tags: c++, move-constructor

I have a class containing a `std::map<int, std::mutex>` and somehow I'm not able to define a move constructor for it. `std::mutex` is not copyable nor movable but the move constructor of `std::map` still works because it doesn't require its type to be copyable or movable:

```
std::map<int, std::mutex> map1;
std::map<int, std::mutex> map2{std::move(map1)}; //this compiles without warnings
```

But then I have a class containing such a map:

```
class OnlyMovable{
  std::map<int, std::mutex> map;
public:
  OnlyMovable(const OnlyMovable&& om) : map{std::move(om.map)} //somehow requires copy-ctor of mutex
  {}
};
```

Here gcc gives me a massive error message which ends with it complaining that `std::mutex` doesn't have a copy-constructor.

So where does the move-constructor of this class invoke the copy-constructor of std::mutex and how is that avoidable?

PS: I know this class makes no sense but its just a simple verifiable example derived from my actual class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your supposed move constructor takes a `const` rvalue reference. `om` cannot be modified, which means its members can't be moved from. Just drop `const`

Comment: No idea where I got that function signature from... thanks.